# How many words per level of the European Language Framework?

Tags: vocabulary, cefr

I recently read an interesting [article](http://www.universeofmemory.com/how-many-words-you-should-know/) that states that for each level of the European Language Framework, you should know approximately this many core words.

Note that a core word can have many words related, but only counts as one word. So in English ‘to sit’, ‘sat’ and ‘sitting’ would all be one core word (verb):

*Language Level: Number of Base Words Needed:*

- A1: 500
- A2:   1000
- B1:   2000
- B2:   4000
- C1:   8000
- C2:   16000

Basically start with *500 words at A1* and then *double* the amount for each level.

***What are the official criteria for this?*** I’m hoping to hear from people at C levels to get an accurate, albeit anecdotal, answer.

Personal experience says yes (give or take 10/20%), I am at B1 with about 1,600 core words known. I do however, hope that I don’t need to learn another 14,000 words plus to get to C2 :)

Comment: Asking for "do you agree with this?" makes the question opinion-based, hence totally off-topic on Stack Exchange network. Consider editing that part with something like "what are the official criteria?" or maybe even "what are the grades according to Language Proficiency Test ___?" We can give only verifiable answers about CEFR, HSK etc.

Comment: How does this question differ from the question [What are estimates of vocabulary size for each CEFR level?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/3061/800)?

Comment: I have edited it. @ChristopheStrobbe the difference is I am not talking about any frameworks such as the CEFR. I am talking about reaching these equivalent levels outside of a formal environment. That question relates to more formal study.

Comment: You *are* talking about frameworks. A1, A2, etc. are level identifiers used in CEFR. These levels can be measured (through language tests) regardless whether you learn a language in a formal context or not.

Comment: As @ChristopheStrobbe mentioned, this question is a duplicate of [this one](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/3061/800).